# RxJs: Observable that emits x times every t seconds with initial delay

Tags: rxjs, settimeout, setinterval

I want to replace a setTimeout & setInterval + counter solution with an Observable to hopefully improve the readability.

How to define a RxJs Observable that that emits x times every t seconds after an initial delay?

I got this so far:

```
interval(t_ms).pipe(delay(d_ms))
```

Comment: timer is what you're looking for https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer

Comment: looks good, is there a simple way to limit it to x emits, without counting and filtering ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Just use `take`, example: `timer(1_000, 10_000).pipe(take(10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timer(initDelayMs,intervalMs)
.pipe(take(n))
```

Starts after `initDelayMs` then emitts `n` times, every `intervalMs` and completes.

- see: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer
- see: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take